# How to install Docker 18.09 on Ubuntu Artful (17.10)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-17.10, buildkite

The Docker repository (https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/) doesn't seem to have higher than 18.06 for Artful. Is there a way to install 18.09? I need that for Buildkit support as right now I'm getting `buildkit not supported by daemon` when trying to build a Dockerfile.

Comment: Did you try to follow the officil docs ? 
https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#docker-ee-customers

I know that for the guideline you need a LTS, but should work in others versions too

Comment: That is exactly what I did. Their repository doesn't have >18.06 for Artful